# How to turn off Lenovo laptop VirtualBox Snail execution mode?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, hyper-v, lenovo-laptop

Configuration:  Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Yoga 3rd Generation Core i7vPro, 16GB main memory, 1TB SSD, Windows 10 Pro 22H2, VirtualBox VM 7.0.6 r155176.

In the above configuration, I have set up a Windows 11 test and familiarization instance.  When checking the startup log, I noticed that the Intel Vt-x hardware isn’t recognized on startup, so Virtual Box runs in Snail execution mode (slowly!):

```
00:00:06.416003 NEM: NEMR3Init: Snail execution mode is active!
00:00:06.416003 NEM: Note! VirtualBox is not able to run at its full potential in this execution mode.
00:00:06.416003 NEM:       To see VirtualBox run at max speed you need to disable all Windows features
00:00:06.416004 NEM:       making use of Hyper-V.  That is a moving target, so google how and carefully
00:00:06.416004 NEM:       consider the consequences of disabling these features.
00:00:06.416004 NEM:
00:00:06.416130 CPUM: No hardware-virtualization capability detected.
```

I checked the UEFI BIOS and found that VT-x and VT-d are both enabled.  So, the hardware is there and turned on.  I know that VB and Hyper-V are mutually exclusive, so I checked the Windows Features to ensure that all Hyper-V items are unchecked.  They are.  It still looks like Hyper-V is active somewhere, since I still see "Snail execution mode" when trying to run a VM instance.  What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I went looking on SuperUser.com and found a [reference](https://superuser.com/questions/1041512/vt-x-not-working-anymore-in-virtualbox) to [Secure System](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/keep-secure/deploy-device-guard-enable-virtualization-based-security) -– a Hyper-V enforced instruction execution level security feature and found out that it uses Hyper-V elements to enforce its security measures.  When I checked, I found that it is turned on for my laptop, as well.

I turned it off (Settings>Update & Security>Windows Security>Device Security>Core isolation details>Memory integrity (set switch to off), Close; done).  Then I opened this note and will now power on the VirtualBox instance to see if Snail execution mode is still active.  OK, done.

Here is the relevant log entry:

```
HM: HMR3Init: VT-x w/ nested paging and unrestricted guest execution hw support.
```

Clearly, the problem is resolved, and VT-x is working as it should.  No more snail execution mode.  OK, done.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling Windows Hyper-V, another option is to use tell VirtualBox to use Hyper-V for its accelleration. Go to your VM settings -> System -> Acceleration -> Paravirtualisation-interface and select Hyper-V.

Apparently that mode is slightly slower than VirtualBox's native mode, (I guess because VM<->virtual hardware communication now requires a cross-VM call) but it should still be much faster than snail mode.